# How to "enhance" jQuery search with $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping over the children of a certain div.

Depending on whether the children are odd or even I have different following operations.

I want to use jQuery's $(this) to get the current context and ADD to the query depending on its state of being odd or even.

If it is an even child I want to get the a child of that div (so this is a child of a child from the loop). How can I do this?

My current method does not work

```
$("div.profile_result").children().each(function(a){
// This way of adding the child a doesn't work
if (a%2) console.log( $($(this) + " > a"))


else console.log("info")
})
```

Comment: lets see the HTML, when you say odd or even, you mean the number or the index ?

Comment: The issue is with the `$($(this) + " > a"))` part. I have the odd and even stuff working.

Comment: It sounds like you want to select `$('div.profile_result > :even > a')`.

Comment: Yeah that would work. If I used two .each() methods I could do it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$($(this) + " > a")` is trying to concatenate an object and a string which you can't do.

Use `$(this).find('a')` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this).index() to decide whether it is odd or even

```
$("div.profile_result").children().each(function(a){
// This way of adding the child a doesn't work
var el = $(this);
var el_index = el.index();//node the index starts from 0;
if ((el_index+1)%2 == 0)
  console.log( el.children() ); // this is even
else 
  console.log("info");
});
```

Comment: `a` is already the index. Why go back to the dom to get something already provided by `each`? OP's issue has nothing to do with getting the index value